# why I cannot found LoginFragmentBindingImpl when using Databinding with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

[image: when i'm running my project i'm getting this error]

As i'm new to data-binding, can Anyone help to fix this. 
[Here is my Fragment](https://codeshare.io/G7y10j)

[Here is my Layout](https://codeshare.io/GAVD0r)

[Here is my gradle](https://codeshare.io/5Zd8jV)

[Here is my ViewModel](https://codeshare.io/5ROnw3)

Comment: Add some codes (layout, activity) to make your question clearer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, added the codes. Would be grateful if you help on this!

Comment: only the XML and the `LoginViewModel` matter.

Comment: Did you enable `dataBinding` on app gradle?

Comment: Yup, i enabled. You can see my gradle above i linked

Comment: I think the fragment binding name should be `FragmentLoginBinding...`, can you check if it exits?

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: onclick is not woking now able to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the variable name of your LoginViewModel from `data` to `viewModel`.

For Example:

```
 <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.xxx.yyy.ui.login.LoginViewModel" />
 </data>
```

After that Rebuild your project

Comment: Changed, while rebuild same issue

Comment: @MuthuS please check logs that will help more in this case

Comment: as per your advice, got to find that on click made issue